# Module non found react native despite installed

Tags: react-native, asynchronous, module, storage

I have a problem with react-native: despite having installed async-storage with the appropriate command and with the right version, I get the following message:
Module not found: Can't resolve '@ rect-native-async-storage / async-storage'
I also sent the npm cache clean --force command to clean the cache, but nothing has changed.
What can I do?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If that is your Module: `@ rect-native-async-storage / async-storage`

Than it is incorrect it should be react.

Be sure to follow every step in here: https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install/